# How to make a temporary ssh pipe?

Tags: networking, ssh-tunneling, file-transfer

I want to transfer gigabytes of data from server A to B. They are in different networks, but both reachable over SSH. I am in another network (neither A nor B's) so instead of tunneling through my system I'd prefer to do the transfer server to server. How can I best do this over an encrypted channel like SSH?

The simplest option might be an encrypted tar pipe (`tar | openssl enc | netcat`), but it doesn't feel very neat.

Another option is to temporarily add a user and use that for an ssh pipe (`tar | ssh`), or temporarily add an authorized key to an existing user and do the same thing. This does allow for a race condition, even if the odds are negligible that one of the servers has malware that is waiting for specific conditions such as these. It also doesn't feel entirely clean.

What is the best way for such a one-off data transfer?

Comment: is simply using scp/sftp not an option? If you want to tar it before sending you can use something like this: http://meinit.nl/using-tar-and-ssh-to-efficiently-copy-files-preserving-permissions . If you clarify your requirements why it has to be a pipe I'll add this as an answer.

Comment: @hyph It's for archiving purposes, so I might as well tar it while it's being read, but it's not a requirement. Scp/sftp has the same issues as ssh: you need to add a user or install an ssh key for an existing user.

Comment: Can you clarify that you are looking for a solution without creating a new user? But to my best knowledge if it has to be secure you'll need a user on the destination server in some way anyhow. edit: you could create a ssh tunnel and then send it over to an anonymous/passwordless regular ftp account.

Comment: Did I understand it correctly that you want to make this transfer without having a valid user, so by bypassing authorization? And you are afraid of malware having access via ssh key?

Comment: @Kalavan Basically. Of course it should be authenticated, but adding users and host keys is meant to last longer. I am wondering whether there is a one-off method of doing this, like an authcode valid for only one session. If that specific example existed I probably would have known about it, but something like that, maybe with another tool that uses ssh or with something like a PAM module. I'm also not *worried*, really, it's more that I'm looking for the neatest way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to establish an SSH connection between A and B, let's say from A to B. It is possible to establish a TCP connection from A to B (B isn't behind a firewall that makes this impossible), but you're concerned that allowing a user from A to log in to B might allow a security breach on B if A isn't trustworthy.

OpenSSH provides a simple solution for that. In [`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS%09FILE_FORMAT), you can restrict a key to be valid to execute one command only. Create a new key pair on A:

```
serverA$ ssh-keygen -N '' -f ~/.ssh/copy_to_B.id_rsa
serverA$ cat ~/.ssh/copy_to_B.id_rsa.pub
```

Take the generated public key and add a forced command at the end of the line. Also add the option `restrict` to prevent things like port forwarding (which could e.g. allow A to make requests that come from inside B's firewall perimeter). The new line in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on B would look like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA… luc@serverA restrict command="cat >~/backups/B/latest.tgz"
```

Now, when using this key to log in to B, the command `cat >~/backups/B/latest.tgz` will be executed regardless of what you pass to `ssh`. This way, all B can do is write to the file

```
serverA$ tar … | ssh -i ~/.ssh/copy_to_B.id_rsa luc@serverB whatever
```

If the SSH server on B is not recent enough, it might not have `restrict`. If it doesn't have `restrict`, then use `no-port-forwarding` instead, plus all the other `no-…` options that are available (check `man sshd` on B).

You can refer to the original command in the forced command through the variable `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`, but beware that if you do something complicated here it would be difficult to ensure that you aren't opening a security hole. Here's a simple wrapper that allows B to write to any file in `~/backups/B` by passing the desired file name as a command — note that the wrapper whitelists characters, to avoid things like writing to `../../.ssh/authorized_keys`.

```
ssh-rsa AAAA… luc@serverA restrict command="case $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in *[!-.A-Za-z0-9_]*) echo >&2 'bad target file'; exit 120;; [!-.]*) cat >~/backups/B/\"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\";; *) echo >&2 'bad target file'; exit 120;; esac"
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know the `authorized_keys` file had more options. I feel a bit bad about taking the accepted answer away from someone else, but this solution keeps security tighter so I guess it's the logical thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to access with a valid user, not only because of the ssh auth, also because of file permissions and ownership.

I really like `rsync` for over-the-net transfers. Incremental data transfers can be resumed, which is foundamental when you don't have full control over the network connection between the 2 servers

Answer (score 1):

If `A` can ssh to `B` and assuming you have a `ssh` agent running:

```
ssh -A A '
  cd /src && tar cf - . | gzip -1 | ssh B "
    cd /dst && gunzip | tar xpf -"'
```

Note that with `-A`, we're giving the remote user on `A` access to your ssh agent. You may not want to do that if you don't trust the admins of that server or whoever may have access to that remote user account. They wouldn't be able to retrieve your ssh keys but could use it for authentication to other machine while that `ssh` command is running.

Comment: If A could ssh to B, there would be no problem. They can reach each other, but how do I have them trust each other without going through something like account creation?

Comment: @Luc, do you mean you don't have access to any user account on B? What I'm saying is that if you can ssh to `B` from your machine using your authentication agent, and network-wise, A can ssh to B, then you can forward your authentication agent to have A use it to ssh to B.

Comment: Ah, I had overlooked that. This is exactly what I was looking for! :D (I thought you just did something like `ssh a 'something | ssh b "something else"'`.)

Comment: But that allows A to execute arbitrary commands on B. My understanding is that the point of the question was to avoid this. @Luc

Comment: @Gilles, that allows *malicious* users (as you need to go through a lot of hoops to be able to do it) on A to execute arbitrary commands on B or any other machine the ssh agent will give you access to while that ssh command is running (and only while it's running as it doesn't give you access to the authentication material), but that's clearly stated in the answer.